I can't seem to find org.apache.lucene.facet.search.params.IFieldSet in Lucene 4.1.0 source even though the JAR from maven has it
I'm trying to migrate the Lucene jars for our product from 4.1.0 to the latest if possible. I noticed that we seem to be using org.apache.lucene.facet.search.params.IFieldSet derived classes for our facet searches but I don't see this in the source code.
Anybody have a clue as to what's happening here?
I've tried

Re-downloading the maven jars to be sure, I dont see it.

UPDATE: Turns out the JAR is checked into the source tree and this particular one is not pulled from Maven


Downloading the tar binaries from lucene archives, don't see it there
Syncing the lucene source code to the tags/releases/lucene-solr/4.1.0 tag, still don't see it

A co worker remarked about the possibility of a fat jar but from what I understand they cannot have conflicting namespaces.
IFieldSet values are also returned from getFieldSet function in org.apache.lucene.facet.search.results.FacetResultNode, for the second and third above that does NOT have IFieldSet, there is also no getFieldSet function.

In which jar did you find IFieldSet (since you're saying that you can still see it) - have you tried grepping for the file across all jars in your project?

lucene-facet-4.1.0.jar. Interestingly this is a jar checked in to our source tree vs pulled from Maven. And of course the original authors who did this have long since left the company. It would be really unfortunate if this was a one off private branch that generated the same binary. FWIW, I downloaded the file from Maven central and don't see IFieldSet there as well.

I'm guessing you have a modified jar that has been modified and then re-built with custom functionality and classes, and it just shares the same name as the original jar file for easier bundling / replacing original functionality. IFieldSet isn't mentioned in associated with lucene in any context I've been able to find, so it seems you have company internal code. I'd try to find out exactly what are using that functionality and whether it's worth keeping - before probably rewriting it with modern Lucene instead - there's been a lot of changes in the 11 years since 4.1.

Yes I believe you're correct. I compared the Jar timestamps and 4.1.0 has Jan 16, 2013 whereas the one checked in by previous owners is Dec 31, 2014, almost 2 years later and contains the extra class (and internal code an interfaces for facets). Whoever did it never bothered to either make a new subminor version or change the name.... sigh. I will close this out

As @MatsLindh helpfully pointed out in the comment above, my company apparently has a custom version of the jar augmented by an employee in the past who built most of the original code.
